# reset method for python to clear all previous values?

Tags: python, methods

I have to convert some code from Sage to python.

One of the first lines of code in Sage is

```
# Clear all previous values from memory and close all open figures
reset()
```

I've been searching everywhere to find the similar method in python. This occurs before any methods are declared.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sage but I'm not sure you need that line in Python. Have you tried just skipping over it?

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you trying to solve by doing something like this? You may not need to do something like this in Python depending on what you actually need.

Comment: it's to calculate the heights and velocities of a ball thrown up in the air at certain times.

Comment: Provided your code is properly designed chances are you don't have to do something like this in Python in most circumstances. If you need to reset variables just do that manually.